# How do i start a Cement CLI prompt

Tags: python, shell, scripting, command-line-interface

I am looking into cement-cli framework(http://builtoncement.com), to build my application. I want my application to be able to support something like the below:

```
ssh into_a_machine
//then run
$ my_cement_cli_app
// this takes me to a prompt from my cement app, where i can run the below
(my_cement_cli_app)> command1 --help
(my_cement_cli_app)> command2 args
(my_cement_cli_app)> command3 args
(my_cement_cli_app)> command4 args .. etc.
```

I am looking at the CEMENT developer docs and it looks like i can do things like

```
python my_cement_cli_app command1 args
or
./my_cement_cli_app command1 args
```

How can i get the CLI prompt to show up? Any help will be appreciated. 
Thanks a lot. If the question sounds vague, please ask me questions and I can clarify.

Answer (score 0):

There is an open issue tracker for shell style support open in GitHub:

- https://github.com/datafolklabs/cement/issues/276

It has not had any attention as of yet, but is something I do plan to work on someday (there hasn't been a lot of interest pushing it).  Please add any additional comments to the issue tracker to help push it along.

Thanks.